# asp.net Log-in doesn't work on firefox browser?

Tags: asp.net

i've log-in page in my site but log-in control doesn't work on any browser other than IE.

please can anyone help me??

thanks

Comment: Post a simplified test case of the code; "it doesn't work" is not enough data to help you.

Comment: Because it works on my machine:)

Comment: Works perfect on every browser !.

Answer (score 0):

If it is browser specific issue, then check if the browser cookies are not disabled. If you have set cookieless="UseCookies" for FormsAuthentication in your web.config, it won't work with cookies disabled on browser.